# php loop with validate class

Tags: php, class, loops

I have this form that is for a hotel website. I need to validate the number of people in a room. The user selects the number of rooms and the number of people in each room. I am looping through the rooms and validating each of them has no more than 4 people, including adults and child.

I have everything pretty much done, but the class I am using seems to not be working on the loop. This is what happens; if the last room on the the list is ok with the number of people the class will allow it to record the data on the database and continue to the next step. However, it will still show the error message that no more than 4 people is allowed in the room. What it should do is go back to the last form and show the error, letting the user select the room again.

This is the code so you might help me with that:

```
foreach ($_POST['adt'] as $key => $adt){
  $chd = $_POST['chd'][$key];

  $v = new validacao;
  echo $v->validarApt($chd, $adt);
  echo $v->validarQpt($qpl);
  echo $v->validarTpl($tpl);
  echo $v->validarChd($chdroom);
  echo $v->validarAdt($adt);

}

if ($v->verifica()) {
```

After this, if validated it should record on the database and continue with the code.

This is the class:

```
<?

class validacao {
    var $campo;
    var $valor;
    var $msg = array();

    function mensagens($num, $campo, $max, $min) {
      $this->msg[0] = "<img src='imagens/x.jpg' /> Os apartamentos neste hotel permitem a acomodação de no máximo 4 passageiros, incluindo adultos e crianças <br />"; // apartamentos  
      $this->msg[1] = "<img src='imagens/x.jpg' /> Este hotel não possui apartamentos quádruplos, por favor selecione 2 apartamentos duplos <br />"; // apartamentos    
      $this->msg[2] = "<img src='imagens/x.jpg' /> Este hotel não possui apartamentos triplos, por favor selecione 2 apartamentos, 1 duplo e 1 single ou faça nova busca e procure por hotéis com apartamentos triplos que tenham preços divulgados em nossa tabela <br />"; // apartamentos    
      $this->msg[3] = "<img src='imagens/x.jpg' /> Este roteiro não dispõe de preços diferenciados para crianças, por favor inclua a criança como adulto <br />"; // apartamentos   
      $this->msg[4] = "<img src='imagens/x.jpg' /> Você deve incluir pelo menos 1 adulto no apartamento <br />"; // apartamentos

      return $this->msg[$num];
    }

    function validarApt($adt,$chd) {
      if ($chd + $adt >= 5) {
        return $this->mensagens(0, null, null, null);
      }
    }   

    function validarQpt($qpl) {
      if ($qpl == 0) {
        return $this->mensagens(1, null, null, null);
      }
    }   

    function validarTpl($tpl) {
      if ($tpl == 0) {
        return $this->mensagens(2, null, null, null);
      }
    }   

    function validarChd($chdroom) {
      if ($chdroom == 0) {
        return $this->mensagens(3, null, null, null);
      }
    }   

    function validarAdt($adt) {
      if ($adt == 0) { 
        return $this->mensagens(4, null, null, null);
      }
    }

    function verifica() {
      if (sizeof($this->msg) == 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should help. You need to add a flag that will be false if any pass through the loop fails, and check that after you're done. You're only checking whether the last pass failed.

```
$verified = true;
foreach ($_POST['adt'] as $key => $adt){
  $chd = $_POST['chd'][$key];

  $v = new validacao;
  echo $v->validarApt($chd, $adt);
  echo $v->validarQpt($qpl);
  echo $v->validarTpl($tpl);
  echo $v->validarChd($chdroom);
  echo $v->validarAdt($adt);

  if(!$v->verifica()){ $verified = false; }
}

if ($verified) {
  ... //proceed with rest of code
}
```

You also have a problem here: (I elide some details for clarity)

```
class validacao {
  ...
  var $msg = array();

  function mensagens($num, $campo, $max, $min) {
    $this->msg[0] = "<img src='imagens/x.jpg' /> Os apartamentos neste hotel permitem a acomodação de no máximo 4 passageiros, incluindo adultos e crianças <br />"; // apartamentos 
    $this->msg[1] = "<img src='imagens/x.jpg' /> Este hotel não possui apartamentos quádruplos, por favor selecione 2 apartamentos duplos <br />"; // apartamentos  
    ...

    return $this->msg[$num];
  }

  ...

  function verifica() {
    if (sizeof($this->msg) == 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

The latter function will ALWAYS return false, because the former function sets a bunch of error messages. Each of your validation functions are returning the result of the `mensagens` function, which is always to return the member variable of the class. You should probably read up on static functions and consider what functions here should be static, which dynamic, and how you store the messages you want to return, and how that differs from the validations that actually fail.

Comment: Thank you so much, but still the same as I described happened

Comment: Echo `$verified` inside your loop. Ensure that some loop fails. Then make sure you provide an 'else' clause that sends you back to the original page. I'm not sure you've provided enough information to diagnose beyond that.

Comment: weird it never changes to false, echoes always true it coninues with the code but the error from the class still show up. lol

Comment: I see whats the problem here, well the code you posted wouldnt work because $verified is still on foreach loop so, whats gonna happen is that $verified will change to whatever value comes last. $verified should be stored in a array, but then I will have to loop the array, wich is not going to help at all. Any other idea my friend?

Comment: Verified will NOT change to whatever comes last. It will change to false if verifica() returns false at any iteration of the loop. Once false, it is never again set to true. See the edit to my post; you have design issues with your verification class.